# How do I structure factory classes to allow for a fluent interface?

Tags: java, oop

I want to create a series of `Actions` that do related things

```
public interface Action{
    public void execute();
}

public class DatabaseAction implements Action{
    public void execute(){}
}

public class WebAction implements Action{
    public void execute(){}
}

public class EmailAction implements Action{
    public void execute(){}
}
```

Generally speaking, users don't care about the details. They want all the actions to run and not worry about it.

But there's going to be some special cases where they only want to run some of the actions, and configure some of the actions.

And I suppose there could be cases where configuration is non-optional.

I figure a fluent interface is the most readable here.

```
// Executes all Actions - intended to be used in almost all cases
// I write to a database, call a web API, and send an email.
Actions.withAllDefaults().execute(); 

// I don't need to send an email and I need to configure the database
Actions.withAction(DATABASE_ACTION)
  .withConfiguration(DatabaseAction.PORT, 9000)
  .withAction(WEB_ACTION)
  .execute();
```

It feels like I should be implementing some sort of factory but it's hard for me to actually translate that into code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Fluent Builder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/fluent-builder-pattern) instead of trying to make your factory fluent.

Comment: All the examples for builders are for instantiating complex objects, and fluent build looks like it's to force users to call each setter method. I'm having a hard time translating that to my use case where configuration is mostly optional and there's multiple classes to choose from. Can you explain further?

Comment: In that case whats wrong with just using a builder and have the build method return an interface level object?

Comment: So a `ActionBuilder` that returns an `Action`? But I have 3 different types of `Actions`, does that mean 3 different calls to `ActionBuilder` if I want all 3 actions?

Comment: Yes - what's wrong with that?

Comment: You can also write a method called buildThree() that just invokes your builder three times

Comment: Even better, buildNActions(...)

Comment: Right but the whole point is that users usually don't want to care about what actions were executed. Most of the time they'll be executing all the actions, regardless of how many I define. If I add a new action, I want it to be executed by default unless they select otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

[C# uses fluent programming extensively in LINQ to build queries using "standard query operators"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#).

This is `C#` implementation. It looks like this sample code can be converted to `Java` as special features of `C#` is not used.

So let's see an example. We start from an interface `IFluent` which allows to build your actions with settings:

```
public interface IFluent
{
    IFluent WithAction(Action action);


    IFluent WithConfiguration(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration);
}
```

and this is `Fluent` class which implements `IFluent` interface:

```
public class Fluent : IFluent
{
    private List<Action> actions;

    public IFluent WithAction(Action action)
    {
        if (actions == null)
            actions = new List<Action>();

        actions.Add(action);
        return this;
    }

    public IFluent WithConfiguration(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration)
    {
        if (actions == null || actions.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no actions");

        int currentActionIndex = actions.Count - 1;
        actions[currentActionIndex].Set(configuration);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then we create an abstract class for `Action` that should define behavior for derived classes:

```
public abstract class Action
{
    public abstract Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }


    public abstract void Execute();


    public abstract void Set(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration);


    public abstract void Add(string name, object value);
}
```

And our derived classes would look like this:

```
public class DatabaseAction : Abstract.Action
{
    public override Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
        = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
    {
        { "port", 0},
        { "connectionString", "foobarConnectionString"},
        { "timeout", 60}
    };


    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is a database action");
    }


    public override void Set(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration)
    {
        if (Properties.ContainsKey(configuration.Key))
            Properties[configuration.Key] = configuration.Value;
    }


    public override void Add(string name, object value)
    {
        Properties.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

and `EmailAction`:

```
public class EmailAction : Abstract.Action
{
    public override Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
        = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "from", "Head First - Object Oriented Design"},
        { "to", "who wants to learn object oriented design"},
        { "index", 123456}
    };

    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is a email action");
    }

    public override void Set(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration)
    {
        if (Properties.ContainsKey(configuration.Key))
            Properties[configuration.Key] = configuration.Value;
    }

    public override void Add(string name, object value)
    {
        Properties.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

and `WebAction`:

```
public class WebAction : Abstract.Action
{
    public override Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
        = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "foo", "1"},
        { "bar", "2"},
        { "hey", "hi"}
    };

    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is a email action");
    }

    public override void Set(KeyValuePair<string, object> configuration)
    {
        if (Properties.ContainsKey(configuration.Key))
            Properties[configuration.Key] = configuration.Value;
    }

    public override void Add(string name, object value)
    {
        Properties.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

The it is possible to call code like this:

```
Fluent actions = new Fluent();
actions.WithAction(new DatabaseAction())
    .WithConfiguration(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("port", 1))
    .WithAction(new EmailAction())
    .WithConfiguration(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("to", "me"));
```